# Inconsistent flagging and close vote behaviour

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

**Flagging**: There are a certain number of flags available in one day worth of reviewing. It doesn't matter whether a user flags by accessing the post from the questions page or from the review pages (Low Quality Posts, First Posts, Late Answers, etc.). Once you've used all your flags, you cannot flag anymore during that day.

**Close Votes**: There are a certain number of close votes allowed in a day when reviewing questions by accessing the Close Votes. Once those votes are used up, you cannot review any more Close Votes. However, you can still access the questions page and vote to close some more questions with another limit of close votes.

Why this inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are a certain number of close votes allowed in a day when reviewing questions by accessing one of the review pages.

That's incorrect. There is a certain number of *reviews* allowed in a day. You can still have some close votes left after you reached the daily maximum of reviewing.

So the behavior is not inconsistent, because the above is the same for flags: you can still have some flags left after you reached the daily maximum of reviewing.

In reply to your comment:

> I think I might not have explained myself properly. Suppose you have
>   10 flags in the whole day. It doesn't matter from where you raised the
>   flags, review pages or normal question pages, you cannot raise more
>   than 10 flags. Now suppose you can review 10 close votes and you've
>   used all of those close votes in the Close Votes page. Even after
>   that, you can go to the question pages and raise more close votes.
>   Isn't that the case?

No, that's not the case. Once you used all your close votes, you cannot cast them anymore (even not on question pages). It doesn't matter where you use your close votes; once you used them all, you cannot cast them anymore.

Comment: Sorry, wrong use of words, have updated the question to reflect the same

Comment: @Divi Ok, thanks for notifying. My answer still applies, so I don't need to edit it.

Comment: I think I might not have explained myself properly. Suppose you have 10 flags in the whole day. It doesn't matter from where you raised the flags, review pages or normal question pages, you cannot raise more than 10 flags. Now suppose you can review 10 close votes and you've used all of those close votes in the Close Votes page. Even after that, you can go to the question pages and raise more close votes. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @Divi No, that's not the case. When you used all your close votes, you used them all and you cannot raise more close votes on question pages.

Comment: @Divi Let's use real numbers: you get 40 reviews and 50 close votes per day. When you did 40 reviews, you can't go into the review queue any more. You still have some votes, though.

Comment: I must be seriously mistaken :)